# How to delete rows in a dataframe based on 2 variables in either column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.6

I have a dataset consisting of 3 columns (Postcode, Borough and Neighbourhood) set up as follows:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Postcode' : ['M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5'], 
            'Borough' : ['Ottawa', 'Not assigned', 'Montreal', 'Toronto', 'Kent'],
               'Neighbourhood' : ['Ottawa', 'Toronto', 'Montreal', 'Barrhaven', 'Not assigned']})
```

which looks like this:

[image: Dataframe]

The values in the columns **Borough** and **Neighbourhood** can either be "Not assigned" or a valid text - the value "Not assigned" could be in both cells, or one or the other.

What I want to do is remove the rows in the entire dataset where it has "Not assigned" in either column.

I am very new to Python ... I thought I would try to create an additional column based on the value of one of the cells, giving True or False, so I tried this...

```
    df['Outcome'] = ["True" if x =='Not assigned' else "False" for x in df['Borough']]
```

... which added an extra column successfully

[image: Dataframe2]

Then I guess I would try and remove those TRUE rows with the drop() function and repeat the process on the Neighbourhood column. But this seems a messy way to do it and I will end up with 20 lines of code where I am sure it can be done much more efficiently.

Can someone please advise me the simplest way to get rid of those rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using bitwise "or" `|`:

```
df_filtered = df[~((df['Borough'] == 'Not assigned') | 
                   (df['Neighbourhood'] == 'Not assigned'))]
```

The result then with your sample dataset is:

```
  Postcode   Borough Neighbourhood
0       M1    Ottawa        Ottawa
2       M3  Montreal      Montreal
3       M4   Toronto     Barrhaven
```

Comment: That's terrific - thank you all so much, got it working :)

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept one of the answers -- with the checkmark -- to let future visitors know the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`DataFrame.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) + **[`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)** with **`axis = 1`** to performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df_filtered = df[df[['Borough','Neighbourhood']].ne('Not assigned').all(axis=1)]
print(df_filtered)
```

**Output**

```
  Postcode   Borough Neighbourhood
0       M1    Ottawa        Ottawa
2       M3  Montreal      Montreal
3       M4   Toronto     Barrhaven
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = df[~(df['Borough'].eq('Not assigned') | df['Borough'].eq('Not assigned'))]
```

```
  Postcode   Borough Neighbourhood
0       M1    Ottawa        Ottawa
2       M3  Montreal      Montreal
3       M4   Toronto     Barrhaven
```